# Get then Replace img src of a nested elemetn without id's

Tags: javascript, image, select, src

I have a HTML structure that we cannot change as it is generated.

I need to look for a specific img src, I need the original src as a val, and also then replace the src with our own custom one.

The structure looks like this:

```
<span id="edit5_WMFStream">
   <div>
      <img src="...">
   </div>
</span>
```

I want to look for the span id ending with WMFStream, and I have nothing to id the nested div and then img. Have tried several things but so far can't even get to select the div, letalone the img then src.

Comment: `images = document.querySelectorAll('[id$="WMFStream"] img')` collects all the images in elements which of `id` ends to "WMFStream". Notice, that the result is a NodeList, you've to iterate it to access the images. Notice, that the HTML structure is invalid, `div` is not permitted content of [span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72626305/get-then-replace-img-src-of-a-nested-elemetn-without-ids), that might cause troubles, because parsers can move the elements, and they're not nested exactly like in the markup.

Comment: It looks like I've managed to bungle the MDN link on my comment above, it should have been this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span

Comment: Irrelevant regarding the HTML structure. As stated, I have no control over it, it is generated with a code builder (PHPRunner).

Will try document.querySelectorAll('[id$="WMFStream"] img')

Comment: It's not irrelevant, browsers might implicitly move the div and its content out of the span, and the DOM query won't find anything. It looks like FF keeps the structure, but there's no rules for how invalid HTML should be parsed, the result may vary across the browsers.

Comment: The selector part worked:

document.querySelectorAll('[id$="WMFStream"] img')

But trying to get the src for each only doesn't using this:

document.querySelectorAll('[id$="WMFStream"] img').getAttribute("src")

Comment: And it is kinda irrelevant, in the fact I cannot do anything about it other than buying the company and fixing the software, which isn't going to happen.

This is what I have to work with.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use querySelector to ref the image

```
document.querySelector("#edit5_WMFStream img")
```

Comment: As stated, I need to select based on the ending in WMFStream. The code will not always be edit5_ it might be edit10_ or any other number.